unusual linking time time while using cmake ExternalProject
I'm trying to build a simple CPP project based on Cmake.
My project has a dependency library(Spdlog).
I like to have my dependency library beside my source files locally so that every time I build my Application I can compile my dependency too.
In this way, I could upgrade my library version whenever I want and am not dependent on its repository when I have no internet access.Also, another positive point of this approach is I don't have to waste my time by compiling the library every time I clean the project.Using this way dependency library will be compiled just once unless I remove the build directory.
In other words I like to have all dependencies locally in my project although I don't like to compile all dependencies after every clean.
this is my simple project structure:
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
├── inc/
│   ├── main.h
├── lib/
│   ├── spdlog/
│   │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   │   ├── include/
│   │   │   └── spdlog/
│   │   │       ├── spdlog.h
│   │   │       ├── ...
│   │   ├── src/
│   │   │   ├── ...
│   │   ├── tests/
│   │   │   ├── ...
│   │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   │   ├── ...
├── src/
│   ├── main.cpp
└── build/

my main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <spdlog/spdlog.h>

int main()
{
    spdlog::info("Hello , World!");

    return 0;
}

and this is my Cmake build script:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(MyProjec)

set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)

# Add ExternalProject_Add for spdlog
include(ExternalProject)
ExternalProject_Add(spdlog_external
    PREFIX ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/spdlog
    SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/spdlog
    BINARY_DIR ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/spdlog_build
    INSTALL_COMMAND ""
    CMAKE_ARGS -DSPDLOG_BUILD_SHARED=ON  # Adjust options as needed
               -DSPDLOG_BUILD_STATIC=OFF
               -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/spdlog_install
    BUILD_COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build . --target install && ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/spdlog/include ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/spdlog_build/include
)

# Set the include directory for the main project
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/inc)
include_directories(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/spdlog_build/include)

# Set the source files for the main project
set(SOURCES
    src/main.cpp
)

# Set the header files for the main project
set(HEADERS
    inc/main.h
)

# Create the executable for the main project
add_executable(MyProjec ${SOURCES} ${HEADERS})

# Specify the include directories for the executable
target_include_directories(MyProjec PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/inc ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/spdlog_build/include)

# Ensure spdlog is built before building the main project
add_dependencies(MyProjec spdlog_external)

# Get the spdlog library path
ExternalProject_Get_Property(spdlog_external BINARY_DIR)
set(SPDLOG_LIB_DIR ${BINARY_DIR})
set(SPDLOG_INCLUDE_DIR ${BINARY_DIR}/include)

# Link the spdlog library to the main project
if (UNIX)
    target_link_libraries(MyProjec PRIVATE ${SPDLOG_LIB_DIR}/libspdlog.so)
else()
    target_link_libraries(MyProjec PRIVATE ${SPDLOG_LIB_DIR}/spdlog.dll)
endif()

Spdlog will compile successfully in normal time and the Cmake copies its headers to the appropriate directory but it took too much time for the linker to link my application to the library and it repeated every time I built ( about 60 seconds on a normal laptop even when I make a simple change in main.ppIs there anything wrong with my Cmake script?

As a downside: you have to redo half of the stuff you get for free with ExternalProject. How often do you clean your project anyway?

Running cmake --install for spdlog on every build won't help your compile times, but I wouldn't think it adds a minute to your build time..

@Botie I agree the way I use ExternalProject has some difficulties like I have to download and put them manually, but let's accept it works for me and I have no problem with that. The requirements are I like to have all dependencies in my project locally while I don't like to compile all dependencies after every clean build.

Shrug. Test for a sentinel file in BUILD_COMMAND and do nothing if it exists?

"I like to have my dependency library beside my source files locally so that every time I build my Application I can compile my dependency too" - Ehh, those two things don't have anything to do with eachother.

I guess it's just a difference in workflow, but I have not had to do a clean build any time recently. Again, shrug.

"it took too much time for the linker to link my application to the library" - If you think that linkage time depends only on the linked library, then you are wrong. The linker reads both the linked library file and objects files of your application. So, if you application is large, then the linker will spend more time on reading its objects files. In other words: probably, spdlog library and your CMake script are absolutely unrelated to your problem.

Your BUILD_COMMAND looks weird. Why do you explicitly copy spdlog header files, if they are accessible from the install tree? If you want specific install directory, just specify INSTALL_DIR option for ExternalProject_Add. Would you remove that copy action, then BUILD_COMMAND will do the same as its default implementation (and default INSTALL_COMMAND). Alternatively, you may do not install spdlog at all. In that case you could use the library file from the build tree (as you already do), and use the include directories from the source tree.
